# How to extract textual content from an SGML DTD using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, sgml

I'm looking into extracting all the content from a DTD using Perl, but I'm not sure which is the best way to go about it.  I know there are modules for working with XML, but I'm not sure if there are any for this type of work with SGML or if I should try to create a regular expression for this work?

I'm new to SGML and Perl along with not having much experience with regex, except for very simple pattern matching.

Comment: Provide some sample input and your expected output.

Comment: Please read the [faq] and [ask] to learn how to properly ask questions here.

Comment: there IS a question here, and it's "should I parse xml with regex". but since it's idiomatic that of course you shouldn't, answered 5,678 times already on this very site, the downvotes.

Comment: ↑↑↑ Sometimes I wish I could downvote comments. ↑↑↑

Comment: I ended up using SGML::DTDParse::DTD.  It is the updated module for perlSGML which was no longer available on CPAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

- use the old [perlSGML](https://metacpan.org/source/EHOOD/perlSGML.1997Sep18/lib/SGML/StripParser.pm) distribution which I have used in the (remote!) past. This being perl it should still run on modern perl,
- convert your SGML to XML using `osx`, which is part of openSP, available for at least Debian/Ubuntu (the package is called `opensp`)and most likely other platforms, then use XML tools like XML::LibXML, or XML::Twig

There are a lot more XML tools than SGML tools these days, but of course you may loose some information since DTDs are slightly simpler in XML than in SGML